# Help with parsing XML with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to use Java-script as a client for java based restful web-service. The service is a survey maker. I am having trouble getting the function to work. The server side of the service is in Google App Engine.  In the code below the function uses http get to get xml representing a list of surveynames, then gets the data from the xml and puts it in a html table. The code is not working, so it would be great if some one could check it to see if I am doing this correctly or I am doing something wrong. I have never programed in javascript so I would also like to know if I need to import a library to use AJAX or is it supported by the browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>View Surveys</title>
</head>
<SCRIPT>
function getSurveyNames(){

    var url = "http://survey-creator.appspot.com/rest/surveymakerpro/allsurveys";
    var xmlhttp;
    // AJAX code for Mozilla, Safari, Opera etc.
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = xmlhttpChange;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    // AJAX code for IE
    else 
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            if (xmlhttp) {
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = xmlhttpChange;
                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
            }
        }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        HTMLSurveyNames = "<table border='1'><tr>Survey Names<th></th></tr>";

        var surveyNames = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("surveys")[0];


        for(var i = 0; i < surveyNames.length ;i++){

            var surveyNameChildNode = surveyName[i].childNodes[0];
            var name = surveyNameChildNode.nodeValue;

            HTMLSurveyNames += "<tr><td>"+name+"</td></tr>";
        }
        //div tags
        document.getElementById('displayNames').innerHTML = HTMLSurveyNames;

    }
}
</SCRIPT>
<body>

<p>View Survey</p>
<form method="post">
    <input name="GetSurveys" style="width: 103px" type="button" value="View all surveys" onClick=getSurveyNames(); /></form>
<p>Here Goes a Table of Surveys</p>
<div id="displayNames">

    <p>Enter the survey you wish to take:</p>
    <form method="post">
        <input id="surveyName" name="SurveyName" style="width: 140px" type="text" value="Enter Survey Name...." /></form>
    <form method="post">
        <input name="Submit2" type="submit" value="Get Survey" /></form>
    <div id="displaySurvey"></div>

</div>
<p>
        <input id="sendtoserver" name="Submit3" type="submit" value="Submit TakenSurvey" /></p>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the xml I want to parse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><surveyNames><SurveyList><surveys>DragonBallZ</surveys><surveys>FootballSurvey</surveys><surveys>NewsSurvey</surveys><surveys>PennstateSurvey</surveys></SurveyList></surveyNames>
```

Comment: You need to read up on [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

1. You're sending off an asynchronous request, but then attempting to immediately process the result before this request will have finished.
2. You should assign a handler to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` that will be executed as your request progresses. You currently assign `xmlhttpChange` to this property, but you don't show what `xmlhttpChange` is. You should be doing something like this:

   ```
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           // XML parsing code goes here
       }
   }
   ```
3. You do not need to import any libraries to use Ajax
4. Be careful with lines like `HTMLSurveyNames = "<table border='1'><tr>Survey Names<th></th></tr>";` You should *always* use the `var` keyword when declaring variables, to avoid creating/modifying globals implicitly.

Comment: by the way, the `// XML parsing code goes here` can be reduced to `// use xmlhttp.reponseXML` as this is a pre-parsed attribute given to the call (if it is a success, and the response was the correct mime-type I believe).  http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsexml-attribute

Comment: @Dan - Right. I really meant to say "XML *processing* goes here".

Comment: Okay I modified the code a little bit but still an getting nothing, am I using DOM correctly?

Comment: @Delanoy - Are you able to `alert` anything in your `onreadystatechange` handler? It's best to take small steps. First, verify that you're getting responses. Then, maybe `toString` the response to make sure it looks OK. Only then you should you try to do anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<table border='1'><tr>Survey Names<th></th></tr>"
```

should be

```
"<table border='1'><tr><th>Survey Names</th></tr>"
```

things will work a LOT better.

there is a cross-browser XML librari for javascript at http://www.softxml.com/softxmllib/softxmllib.htm
I believe XMLHTTPRequest() is specific to IE.  there are versions for other browsers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest